# Minima of a two-variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Find the global minima of a two-variable function:
$$f(x,y) = (x-2y)^2 -1$$
I have already found partial derivatives in x and y:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = 2x - 4y $$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = -4x + 8y $$

And I see that any number satisfies those 2 equations. Here I don't know what to do next.
Can somebody help me with this problem?
Thank you

Comment: considering putting both derivative as 0

Comment: You don't need partial derivatives. You know that $(x-2y)^2\geqslant 0$ so that the minimum is $-1$.

Comment: Since both deritatves are 0 you can set them equal: $2x-4y=-4x+8y\Rightarrow x=2y$. Next you insert 2y for x in one of the two equations. You will see that for all value of y the equation are valid. Thus the global minimum is $(x,y)=(2y,y)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ equal to $0$ we get
$x=2y$, and every such solution also makes $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ vanish, so these are all the critical points. However, we are looking for global extrema, rather than local ones.

Pure algebra will do the trick, and there is no need for partial derivatives: $(x-2y)^2-1$ is minimal when $(x-2y)^2$ is minimal and that happens when $x-2y=0$ i.e. $x=2y$. Therefore all points $(x,y)$ of the form $x=2y$ are global minima and the minimal value is $-1$.